# How to get all rows of a dataframe NOT designated in a vector in R?

Tags: r

I'm looking for an elegant, R-like way to capture rows in a dataframe that don't have their indices listed in a vector:

```
table.combos <- matrix(data = 1:12, nrow = 10, ncol = 6, byrow=T)
table.combos
not.these<-c(2,4,5,9)
x<-table.combos[c(not.these),]
#y<- everything not in x
```

Comment: In other words, I'm looking for y.

Comment: `y <- table.combos[-not.these,]` is not enough?

Comment: That works! I just didn't know that the subtraction operator worked like that in R. If you put it as an answer, I'll go ahead and designate it as such. Thanks, @Jilber!

Comment: You may wish to have a look at `?Extract`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the same index vector as in:

```
y <- table.combos[-not.these,]
```

which tells chose all the rows from `table.combos` but those contained in `not.these` vector.